# Is it dangerous to leave Synaptic Package Manager open?

Tags: package-management, sudo, security, root, synaptic

Just a thought that crossed my mind. Usually when I run Synaptic Package Manager, I do it with `sudo`, because obviously it is fairly useless otherwise.

Sometimes I just leave it open; is this dangerous, similar to if I were running a desktop as root? Why or why not?

Comment: Why it should be dangerous? Give some of your reasons first

Comment: @Anwar There is a big taboo of running linux distributions as a root user.  `sudo` privileges are designed to time out, so you don't forget to log out as root. Well; does that imply that leaving an application open that requires root privileges is also taboo?

Comment: If someone can access your system then leaving any application with sudo privilege can be a risk .Not just synaptic package manager. The timeout was there to prevent this